# Swift: string with placeholder for variables to be passed in during 'print()'

Tags: python, swift, string, variables

*EDIT: Ok, the responses have helped me figure out the terminology I need to be using to more clearly describe this question. Thank you!*

Transitioning from Python to Swift, I'm trying to replicate some educational exercises, and there's a process Python can do with string interpolation that uses a sort of a generic "placeholder" space in a string literal that can be passed a value at a later time.

It would look something like:

```py
color = "purple"
size = "large"

description = "My car is the {} one over there."

print(description.format(color))
print(description.format(size))
```

and would return:

```
> My car is the purple one over there.
> My car is the large one over there.
```

So:

- The sentence string is assigned to a variable
- It has a "placeholder" for variables with the `{}`
- Invoking `print()` and attaching the `format()` function to the sentence variable allows it to pass in another variable to be inserted as a string literal at the "placeholder"

For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to replicate this particular method of string interpolation in Swift. <s>In particular, attempting to mimic Python's `{}` with `\()` isn't allowed,</s> *[EDIT: looks like `%@` is the answer for that issue]* and trying to attach functions to variables in `print()` when strings are involved is causing a bunch of different issues depending on what I try.

How can I perform the Python task in Swift? Am I missing something simple and just don't know the terminology *[likely]* which is making this more difficult than it should be, or is this kind of string interpolation not something that Swift can do?

*EDIT 2: Attached snippets of code I'm working with*

```
let hilarious = false
let joke_evaluation = "Isn't that joke so funny?! %@"

print(joke_evaluation)
print(String(format: joke_evaluation, arguments: [hilarious])) // Extra argument 'arguments' in call
```

```
struct carStuff {
    let color = "red"
    let size = "large"
    let description = "The %@ car."
    init(format: String, arguments: [CVarArg]) // Initializer requires a body
}

print(String(format: carStuff.description, arguments: carStuff.color)) // Extra argument 'arguments' in call
```

[image: Code Snippet]

Comment: Start with the [Docs for `String`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string), look for the section on "Creating a String Using Formats". Then do some research into how `String` formating works in C/Java/ObjC, as they are all basically using the same concept

Comment: "trying to attach functions to variables in `print()` when strings are involved is causing a bunch of issues" - do you mean the `String(format:`? What issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally in Swift you can just use [String Interpolation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html#ID292) `\()`. This is just like Python's [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/).

```
let color = "purple"
let size = "large"
print("My car is the \(color) one over there.") /// My car is the purple one over there.
print("My car is the \(size) one over there.") /// My car is the large one over there.
```

That should be fine for most cases. But if you want an explicit placeholder, check out [`init(format:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/3126742-init).

```
let color = "purple"
let size = "large"
let description = "My car is the %@ one over there."
print(String(format: description, color)) /// My car is the purple one over there.
print(String(format: description, size)) /// My car is the large one over there.
```

Use `%@` for `String` values like `color`. Here's the [full list of placeholders](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html), in case you want format an `Int` or something else.

---

#### Edit: Based off OP's code snippets

Your first code snippet compiles fine for me. However, `%@` only supports `String` and [other objects that bridge to obj-c](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/object_runtime/classes_bridged_to_swift_standard_library_value_types) — `Bool`s like `hilarious` don't work. You need to convert it to a `String` first.

```
let hilarious = false
let joke_evaluation = "Isn't that joke so funny?! %@"
print(String(format: joke_evaluation, arguments: [String(hilarious)])) /// Need to convert `hilarious` to a String first
```

> **Result:**
> Isn't that joke so funny?! false

Your second code snippet has a couple problems. I think you might be confusing Apple structs like `String` with custom, made-by-you structs like `CarStuff`. But anyway, if you want to make your own struct `CarStuff` (again, *why?*), here's how:

- `carStuff` is a struct, so it should be capitalized to `CarStuff` (just good conventions).
- The purpose of an initializer is to initialize all of the struct's properties.
- structs get initializers for free, so you don't need to define one. But if you want to make your own, you need to make sure that *all the properties are initialized* once `init()` is called. See the [docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html) for more information.
- Your initializer, `init(format: String, arguments: [CVarArg])`, doesn't have a body. This is a syntax error - you need the curly braces `{}`.
- Also, why is your initializer defined as `init(format: String, arguments: [CVarArg])`? The properties of `CarStuff` are `color`, `size`, and `description`. What does `format` and `arguments` have to do with those? Remember: *The purpose of an initializer is to initialize all of the struct's properties.*

```
init(format: String, arguments: [CVarArg]) {
    /**
     initialize the struct's properties here.
     but, you already provided default values to the properties...
     ... for example, `let color = "red"`
     so you don't even need your custom init — Swift does it automatically for you.
     And besides, what is `format` and `arguments` for?
     Just remove this `init` entirely.
     */
}
```

Anyway, all of that was just some extra info, not really related to your original question. The real problem is that there are 2 very similar `String` initializers:

- [`init(format:arguments:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/3126743-init)
- [`init(format:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/3126742-init)

The first one requires you to pass in an `Array`. The second one takes in a variadic number of parameters, so you can just directly pass in your variable to be substituted.

```
struct CarStuff {
    let color = "red"
    let size = "large"
    let description = "The %@ car."
}
let carStuff = CarStuff() /// initialize a `CarStuff` (using Swift's auto-generated initializer)
print(String(format: carStuff.description, arguments: [carStuff.color])) // init(format:arguments:) requires an array
print(String(format: carStuff.description, carStuff.color)) // init(format:_:) lets you omit `arguments` and directly pass in your arguments
```

> **Result:**
> The red car.
> The red car.

Comment: Ok, this is getting me riiiiiiight up to the edge of being solved, but it throws the error `Extra argument 'arguments' in call`, and following the String Interpolation link is sending me down the right path, but I start going down rabbit holes of `struct` and `extension` and the like, which feels like I'm over-complicating the issue.

Comment: @Texian weird, can you upload a screenshot? The compiler might be getting confused with [`init(format:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/3126742-init) which is probably the better approach actually (instead of taking in an array, it takes a variadic number of arguments). I'll update my answer.

Comment: Sure thing; I just added a screenshot.

Comment: @Texian does that clear things up? If so, can you click the green checkmark to accept the answer?

Comment: Sorry, been out of pocket for several days. YES! That information was extremely helpful. I'll add the checkmark right away.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift we can do this as follows:

```
let color = "purple"
let size = "large"
print("My car is the \(color) one over there.") 
print("My car is the \(size) one over there.")
```